# How to check if user have zoom from js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, zooming

I have specific js (svg drawings, etc) on site and I am not able to create it supercool when user has zoom (can't calculate correct needed values).
So I want to prevent user actions if user zoom value is not 100%.

I tried to use [detect-zoom](https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom)
and this is a bad solution:

- For Chrome (os x, Yosemite) have 0.98-1 values while 100% zoom.
- For Safari - 0.88
- For Firefox - 2.0

And I can say that this is not working sometimes and for Chrome. For example, right after I exit fullscreen mode (videos on site is critical functionality) - library return 1.1 zoom value for one moment.

Also, this is only OS X platform and last versions of browsers. So I guess on other platforms/versions of browsers I can get another different values.

How I should resolve this situation (get correct values). Maybe someone already has a good solution?

Thanks